# Write to Paragraph from Text Inputs with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on some code that takes the inputs from two textboxes, one that takes a string value and one that takes a number value, and in real time writes it to a paragraph without a submit button. I am having trouble finding any information on this process without submitting anything. The paragraph should just display . To begin, this is what I have:

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (

    <div>
      <form>
        <div>String:</div>
      <input type="text" strng = "strng" /><br/><br/>
        <div>Number:</div>
      <input type="text" strng = "number"/><br/><br/>
      <button>Clear</button>
      <p>
        Inputs: 
      </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
  }
  export default App;
```

Would someone be able to help me out with writing the two text boxes to the paragraph in real time? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: The values being entered into the two `input` elements need to be tracked/stored at some place (typically, in react, this may get stored into what is called a `state`). May be try declaring: `const [inputNum, setInputNum] = React.useState(''); const [inputStrng, setInputStrng] = React.useState('');`. And then, in the `input`s try something like: `<input type="text" value={inputNum} ..... />` and `<input type="text" value={inputStrng} ..... />`. And finally, on the paragraph: `<p> Input: number is - {inputNum} and text is - {inputStrng} </p>`.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: You need to listen to `onChange` events and deal with them in some function defined in the function body of `App`. I'm not really sure exactly what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to add the two fields together, then you just need to run a function that takes the values of the input fields, concatenates them together, then set the value of the paragraph to be the return value of that function.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to bind a [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) with the onChange event of the input

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <div>String:</div>
        <input
          type="text"
          strng="strng"
          onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div>Number:</div>
        <input type="text" strng="number" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button>Clear</button>
        <p>Input: {text}</p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```